# PowerShell - Removing Items from Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to remove items from an array that match special keywords. My array looks something like this:

```
$Printers =@('Printer Phone', 'Printer Building1', 'Printer XML', 'Printer Station', ...)
```

I want to remove all entries that match parts of certain strings, like filtering out every item that has "Phone" or "XML" in it's value. I thought of something like this but I'm not quiet sure if I'm on the right track:

```
$contains = @('Phone', 'XML')
$Printers -Filter * | Where-Object { $contains -contains $_.name }
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `$Printers |Select-String -NotMatch $Contains`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this.

```
> $contains = @('Phone', 'XML')
> $Printers = @('Printer Phone','Printer Building1','Printer XML', 'Printer Station')
> $Printers | Where-Object { $_ -Match ($contains -Join "|") }
Printer Phone
Printer XML
> $Printers | Where-Object { $_ -notMatch ($contains -Join "|") }
Printer Building1
Printer Station
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution, but it would help if you explained it a bit and mentioned the potential need to apply `[regex]::Escape()` to the search terms (not necessary with the sample input). Also, it would help if you allowed readers to copy and paste the solution as-is in order to try it, in a single operation, without having to remove the `> ` prefixes or having to copy and paste the relevant part of each line individually.

Answer (score 3):

Three remarks

- You don't need `@()` to make arrays. The *comma* is what makes arrays, the `@()` is redundant here.
- The PowerShell `-contains` operator does *not* check whether a string contains a substring. It checks whether an array contains a value.
  Using [the .NET `.Contains()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) works for substring checks, but be aware, it's case-sensitive. Lower-case your strings if you need case-insensitive comparisons (good enough and easier than [doing it "by the book"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)).
- Any value that you produce in a `{}` script block and *don't* assign to a variable, will become part of that script block's output. That's how the `Where-Object` block below works.

Code:

```
$Printers = 'Printer Phone','Printer Building1','Printer XML', 'Printer Station' 
$contains = 'Phone','XML'

$Printers | Where-Object { 
    $printer = $_
    $contains | Where-Object {  $printer.Contains($_) }
}
```

`Where-Object` considers non-empty output as `$true`. So filtering `$contains` down to something (or nothing) will decide whether the `$Printers` value makes it. The above prints

```
Printer Phone
Printer XML
```

You could use `-match`, but then you would have to start worrying about regex-escaping your `$contains` values properly to avoid run-time errors.

Comment: Just as a matter of practice, it's *always* a good idea to add @() around your arrays, even if it looks redundant.  Arrays with one element otherwise easily get turned into single items instead of arrays.  For example, `(GetList) + "XML"` is very  different than `@(GetList) + "XML"`, if the GetList function returns an array of only one element.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an array of patterns with select-string.  But select-string's output is a matchinfo object (unless it's converted to a string) and the line property has the original string examined.

```
$patterns = echo Phone XML
$printers = 'Printer Phone', 'Printer Building1', 'Printer XML',
  'Printer Station'
$printers | select-string $patterns | % line
```

```
Printer Phone
Printer XML
```

Unfortunately, -contains is a frequent point of confusion.

```
'printer station' -contains 'station'

False


-split 'printer station' -contains 'station'

True
```

Comment: Nice, though it's safer to add `-SimpleMatch` in this case, for _literal_ substring searches. In PowerShell (Core) 7+, `-Raw` is now available for direct output of the matching lines as strings; e.g. `$printers | select-string -Raw -SimpleMatch $patterns`